# Python: How to store 2 sound files overlapped with each other

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pyaudio, pydub

I am trying to make a beat pad, for that I need to be able to play many sounds together, playing them together isnt the problem. What I cant figure out is how I can store the sounds played overlapped with eachother. For example, if I play a kick, snare then kick and snare and then along with it (in usison) I play a guitar chord, how do I do that?
This is the code I've written but it just adds the kick after the snare. I want them to play together

```
f = open ('Kick1.mp3', 'rb')
file = f.read()
f.close()

f = open ('Snare1.mp3', 'rb')
file1 = f.read()
file3 = file1 + file

x = open ('Kick3.mp3', 'ab')
x.write(file3)
```

Comment: You are not playing any sounds, only concatenating two files. While this might accidentally work for those files that will not work in general even to play one after the other. You have to decode the mp3 files, work with the actual sound in them and at the end encode them back to mp3.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Find an mp3 module for python

Comment: I tried using pydub but it didn't work cause I'm missing  ffmpeg, can anyone tell me how to install it in pycharm?

Comment: @Curran-C if you have the ffmpeg executable for your platform you can put it in the root directory of your python project (or symlink it)